# File exists when the application is first started

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I can't understand why the application, even though I uninstalled it and tried it on two different phones, when I first start it, it doesn't do the if, but instead executes the code else. Until now it worked but now it doesn't. What can it be?

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        Device.SetFlags(new[] { "Brush_Experimental", "Expander_Experimental" });
        InitializeComponent();
        
        string setting = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "setting.txt");

        if (!File.Exists(setting))
            MainPage = new BenvenutoPage();
        else
            MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code to create the file?

Comment: What does it mean “until now”?

Comment: [c#](https://i.postimg.cc/Ss9Ws4bX/Immagine.png) The file shouldn't exist if the app I remove it from the phone and then start it the first time. Until yesterday it worked correctly. The file is created on the 'BenvenutoPage' page

Comment: Has it been added by accident to the project as "Build Action: Copy to output"?

Comment: how do I check it?

Comment: Do you mean the code work now but does not work before?